# What do these diode markings mean?

Tags: diodes

I have a diode that reads F or 4, 65, B, but I can't find any information about what these markings mean online.

I don't have the original packaging so I'm at a loss.

Does anyone know what this means?

Or know a way that I can test the diode and work out what it is?

I am hoping its a 15V Zener, but that seems unlikely.

[image]

Comment: It's the Fairchild *f*, I think.

Comment: Okay, looking into that now - any idea on what the 65 and B refer to?

Comment: Please recheck the code on that diode.

Comment: It definitely has a 65 under the F and a B under that - I've checked with a microscope to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually those numbers are marking information. Different manufacturers will have different markings.

Go through this [article](https://www.videojet.com/content/dam/pdf/NA%20-%20English/Application-Notes/an-coding-and-marking-electronic-components-us.pdf) which gives good information on coding and marking on electronic components.

The F indicates it is from Fairchild semiconductors.

65 indicates 15V.

Please go though this [datasheet.](http://eeshop.unl.edu/pdf/1N9xxB.pdf) Page 2 and 3 have marking information .